# Failed to @Mock Autowired Object

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I have a following class where I was unable to mock an autowired object I get null in Tested class on **SomeServiceBean** mock.Any Help would be appreciated.

```
@DynamicReadable
@Component
public class DaoBean extends SomeBean implements Dao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SomeServiceBean someServiceBean;

    @Override
    public void getId(String name) {
        String email = someServiceBean.getEmail(name);
        return jdbcTemplate.query("query here")
    }

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class DaoBeanTest {
    
        @InjectMocks
        private DaoBean systemUnderTest;
    
        @Mock
        private SomeServiceBean someServiceBean;
    
        @Mock
        private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;
    
    
        @Test
        public void testId() {
            Mockito.when(someServiceBean.getEmail(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("johndoe@gmail.com");
            String result = systemUnderTest.getId("johndoe");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does 'get null' mean? Please add the exception and full stack trace to your question.

Comment: (if you just mean that `getId` returns null, then that's expected.)

Comment: Use constructor injection instead of field injection and your problems will go away.